# Why is [NSSet allObjects] not returning an array of objects in the set

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsset

I'm following a `[NSManagedObject valueForKeyPath:...]` and then checking the result returned by that *query* to see whether it's a single NSManagedObject, or an NSSet of managed objects.  If it's an NSSet, i'm trying to transfer it to an NSArray using `[NSSet allObjects]`

It is not returning an NSArray of the members of the NSSet as expected.

> guids = [result allObjects]

`result` is in fact an NSSet, but it's giving me back an array with the NSSet inside it.

When I ask the array how many objects are in it, I get '1' as my answer...

> [guids count]     **// returns 1**

```
    NSArray *guids;

    id result = [someNSManagedObject valueForKeyPath:kvcPath];

    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSSet class]])
    {
        guids = [result allObjects];
    }
```

[image]

Even replacing the `guids = [result allObjects]` with an enumerator and an NSMutableArray doesn't work...

```
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSSet class]])
    {
        NSEnumerator *setEnumerator = [result objectEnumerator];
        NSString *value;

        while (value = [setEnumerator nextObject]) {
            [guids addObject:value];
        }
    }
```

Look at the picture below (hilarious), the enumerator supposed to be looking at a single value from the set, but it's instead looking at the entire set as the value.

[image]

Comment: What's the code for putting items into the set?

Comment: I'm following a core data relationship, which as you know either gives you a single NSManagedObject, or an NSSet of NSManagedObject depending on how many items it finds in the relationship.

Comment: This sounds more like a rant than a question there really isn't anything here that we can use to help you. Just state the facts. Show the code. What, for example, is rpInfo? Etc...

Comment: rpInfo is an NSManagedObject

Comment: Also, why use NSEnumerator and not just for string in set?

Comment: I should simply be able to do arrayVariable = [setVariable allObjects] but as I show above, that does not work, and neither does attempting to enumerate the objects in the NSSet using an enumerator.  I'm not the one putting the objects into the set... I'm following a NSManagedObject's relationships using a keypath, and it is giving me a populated set.  I have no control over that side of it.

Comment: Too ranty, and you're not showing your real-and-complete code so it's impossible to help. Try to learn to assume that _you_ are making a mistake rather than scoffing at Xcode. Plus there are some traps as to how tooltips work; instead of using tooltips, pause _after_ code that sets the value you want and use the variables pane of the debugger, which is much more reliable.

Comment: Looks like you have a set which contains another set which contains strings.

Comment: @rmaddy ... good catch... that was very unexpected, but you are correct.  I'll give you credit if you want to put it as an answer... meanwhile I answered it and mentioned your insight in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With credit to ***rmaddy*** in the comments above, it turns out this is an NSSet within an NSSet.

Contrast these two paths for the explanation that follows

`someParentManObj.someRelatedChildManObj`

versus

`someParentManObj.someRelatedChildManObj.someFieldOnChildManObj`

Apparently, if you follow NSManagedObject paths just to a relationship, and no further, such as a field, then you'll get back either ...
(1) a single NSManagedObject at the other end of the relationship, or 
(2) an NSSet of NSManagedObjects at the other end of the relationship.

However, if you tweak the path such that it ends in a field name on a NSManagedObject, you won't get an NSSet of values, rather you get an NSSet wrapped in an NSSet.